# Xamarin Forms, HttpClient class - GetStringAsync and GetAsync return null value and exit from function quickly

Tags: c#, xamarin, httpclient, system.net.httpwebrequest

when I run my code, in my function that call GetStringAsync or GetAsync, this 2 calls returns null value and immediately exit from my function (all code after is unreached )

I make a web api that is is reachable from web browser [(url reached on browser)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjTUx.png) , also in the emulator browser ( [Browser on the Android Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUYqL.png) ) then i try to make a xamarin forms that manages to communicate with it

```
class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;



    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        GetEmployees();
    }



    private async void GetEmployees()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var uri = "http://192.168.1.135:8092/api/Masters/GetEmployees/";

            var result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);


            var EmployeeList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(result);

            Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(EmployeeList);
        }

    }

    ObservableCollection<Employee> _employees;

    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees
    {

        get
        {
            return _employees;
        }

        set
        {
            _employees = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Employee));

        }

    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

or

```
class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private const string ApiBaseAddress = "http://192.168.1.135:8092/api/Masters/GetEmployees/";

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        GetEmployees();
    }

    private HttpClient CreateClient()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(ApiBaseAddress)
        };

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        return httpClient;
    }

    private async void GetEmployees()
    {

        using (var httpClient = CreateClient())
        {
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(ApiBaseAddress).ConfigureAwait(false);

            var test = response;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(json))
                {
                    var EmployeeList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(json);

                    Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(EmployeeList);

                }

            }

            response.Dispose();
        }
    }

    ObservableCollection<Employee> _employees;

    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees
    {

        get
        {
            return _employees;
        }

        set
        {
            _employees = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Employee));

        }

    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I expect that  `var result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);`

or

```
 var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(ApiBaseAddress).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

returns something but the actual output is null and the code after is unreached because this 2 calls exit immediatly from the function

Comment: Have you tried to access to that url with your browser?

Comment: yes, I already said that with the browser it works, only with calls, unfortunately, does not work

Comment: Maybe your running emulator (Android or iOS) don't have access to that url, can you start your emulator, use the installed browser and try to enter into that url?

Comment: Try the URL in the device browser.

Comment: using (var httpClient = CreateClient()) is wrong, HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I tried and in the browser of Android Emulator it Works correctly ( I added a Photo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid mixing async/await and blocking calls like .Wait() or .Result

Refactor your code to be async all the way through.

```
public MainPageViewModel()
{
   var EmployeeList =  GetEmployees();
   Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(EmployeeList.Result);
}



private async Task<List<Employee>> GetEmployees()
{
   using (var httpClient = CreateClient())
   {
     var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(ApiBaseAddress).ConfigureAwait(false);

     var test = response;

     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
       var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

       if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(json))
       {
          var EmployeeList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(json);

          return EmployeeList;

       }                    

     }

     return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Throws Exception: Cleartext HTTP traffic to 192.168.1.135 not permitted

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted

Comment: I've already read it but for me is not working. I belive my problem is the ssl certificate because if i try to connecting to web api with https, I can't

Comment: Did you try to change another url?

Comment: Ok, problem solved adding these lines of code into AndroidManifest.xml  <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>

Comment: Happy coding :)